# How to display all rows in Grdiview without displaying scrollbar

Tags: c#, gridview

I have gridview with few hundreds rows, how can I force the gridview to extend it's hight and display all rows without scroolbar?

C# 3.0 / .net 3.5 /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) has several things which could help you to calculate the height:

- [DisplayedColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.displayedcolumncount.aspx)
- [DisplayedRowCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.displayedrowcount.aspx) - in relation to [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx).Count
- [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) -> [GetRowsHeight()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.getrowsheight.aspx)
- [ColumnHeadersHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheight.aspx)
- [RowTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate.aspx) - [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.height.aspx)

But i would be really interested on which display resolution you display a few hundred rows without scrolling.

Last but not least (nor tested): Take a look into the properties `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode`

Answer (score 0):

You want display all the handreds rows without scrrolbar. you must change the height of the GridView when you load data.

> ```
> DataGridView.Height= xxx
> Load data
> ```

Comment: How to find the height in this case?